# openstack service can not find the reply exchange of rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, openstack

My environment is **openstack** communicating on **rabbitmq**, just one rabbitmq node, not a cluster;

I find one compute node can't work , *nova-compute service can't get ack of the rpc request from nova-conductor service*.

And at the same time ,there are many logs like below in nova-conductor log.

Anyone know it ?

```
2016-06-07 14:37:54.184 13820 INFO oslo_messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [req-83bfbe28-3729-4756-8dc3-fc1d8a05d71f - - - - -] The exchange to reply to reply_9270c332921a4fadb6b370fec2ecce16 doesn't exist yet, retrying...
2016-06-07 14:37:54.186 13820 INFO oslo_messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [req-a9b99ca4-4dc2-4bb9-b003-279a7fab9aa4 - - - - -] The exchange to reply to reply_9270c332921a4fadb6b370fec2ecce16 doesn't exist yet, retrying...
2016-06-07 14:37:54.214 13820 INFO oslo_messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [req-c7d6e857-f73e-45c3-9f1e-d92760822a2a - - - - -] The exchange to reply to reply_9270c332921a4fadb6b370fec2ecce16 doesn't exist yet, retrying...
2016-06-07 14:37:54.224 13822 INFO oslo_messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [req-7be21851-d331-47f7-a0fc-8225a65ba68f - - - - -] The exchange to reply to reply_9270c332921a4fadb6b370fec2ecce16 doesn't exist yet, retrying...
2016-06-07 14:37:54.225 13822 INFO oslo_messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [req-b14f1618-1fe7-4804-bb4d-25e87d9f764a - - - - -] The exchange to reply to reply_9270c332921a4fadb6b370fec2ecce16 doesn't exist yet, retrying...
2016-06-07 14:37:54.263 13824 INFO oslo_messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [req-72e2a5fe-21b5-4221-bc00-3990e8f8d10e - - - - -] The exchange to reply to reply_9270c332921a4fadb6b370fec2ecce16 doesn't exist yet, retrying...
2016-06-07 14:37:54.263 13824 INFO oslo_messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [req-b97dfd77-0955-4919-a4f1-469c73a6eb34 - - - - -] The exchange to reply to reply_9270c332921a4fadb6b370fec2ecce16 doesn't exist yet, retrying...
2016-06-07 14:37:54.269 13824 INFO oslo_messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [req-ebb588bf-85ca-43ef-95d6-f755a28bb5be - - - - -] The exchange to reply to reply_9270c332921a4fadb6b370fec2ecce16 doesn't exist yet, retrying...
2016-06-07 14:37:54.281 13823 INFO oslo_messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [req-b14f1618-1fe7-4804-bb4d-25e87d9f764a - - - - -] The exchange to reply to reply_9270c332921a4fadb6b370fec2ecce16 doesn't exist yet, retrying...
2016-06-07 14:37:54.313 13823 INFO oslo_messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [req-3b5b4e32-dc3e-457d-9e48-ae545e4b34a7 - - - - -] The exchange to reply to reply_9270c332921a4fadb6b370fec2ecce16 doesn't exist yet, retrying...
2016-06-07 14:37:54.342 13820 INFO oslo_messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [req-6692ac00-97a1-4ef4-9b05-8b271c6a2009 - - - - -] The exchange to reply to reply_9270c332921a4fadb6b370fec2ecce16 doesn't exist yet, retrying...
```